# Is oauth a reserved word in Bluemix API management?

Tags: api, oauth, ibm-cloud, ibm-api-management

I have configured two urls in the Bluemix API management service

```
https://api.apim.ibmcloud.com/persistentserver/persistentappdev/api/login
https://api.apim.ibmcloud.com/persistentserver/persistentappdev/api/oauth/token
```

Both APIs use the same proxy url, i.e `http://[server name]/api/login`
When `https://api.apim.ibmcloud.com/persistentserver/persistentappdev/api/login`
 is invoked, it works as expected
However when `https://api.apim.ibmcloud.com/persistentserver/persistentappdev/api/oauth/token` is invoked, I receive the following error:

```
{ "error": "invalid_client", "error_description": "client_id invalid" }
```

In this case the request does not reach to the proxy endpoint (confirmed through logs). Is oauth a reserved word in the API management service?  Does the service do its own validation when it encounters the word in a url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid conflicts with API Management's built-in oauth token service, some constraints have been placed on the oauth word when used in creating operations, . Specifically, `/oauth/token` and `/oauth/authorize` should not be used.